An exception occured on running simple new Flutter App project
I have created a new Flutter App and just to try the app on my device. But it is giving the following error.
Build file 'D:\sample_projects\we_connect\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ApplicationExtensionImpl$AgpDecorated.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintImpl$AgpDecorated.
         > Could not generate a decorated class for type LintImpl$AgpDecorated.
            > com/android/tools/lint/model/LintModelSeverity has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

I have already searched this issue and tried some solution but nothing working so far.
I have tried change Gradle JDL to version 11. I have also upgrade gradle to latest version 8.10.1 and and update gradle-wrapper.properties.

That error is related to Java more than anything else: that "version 55" means that you're using a Java version 11, while gradle has been compiled with Java version 17 (the "61" version mentioned). You need to find out how to upgrade the Java version gradle is using.

I ended up in reinstalling android studio and Flutter whch took max an hour. Now everything's works fine.
